# A Way to change the datatype of the column in a tsv file of a dataset permanenetly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have a dataset of data colleceted from the twitter api that has a 19 digit id column. The issue has been that whenever i load the dataset the with pandas the following problem happens as shown in the image [The id column turncates to float and removes important digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEeq6.png). Since these numbers are the primary key for the table i need them complete to use. I deduced that the problem arose from the fact that while reading the dataset reads the datatype for the id column as float.

I have tried changing the datatype of the id column to int64 using the apply method and saving the dataset after that. I expected that to remain permanent but it did not. Also while loading the dataset if a specify before hand that datatype should be kept np.int64 using the dtype attribute in the read_table method, the id is read correctly showing all 19 digits. But I would like to remove the need to do so.

Comment: CSV/TSV doesn't keep a dtype information, if you have a specific one you **must** state it explicitly, else the parser will try to guess the ideal one, which doesn't suit your case.